# Ncover integration with CC.Net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ncover

I'm using NCover 3.0 .Want to integrate the results into CC.Net .Everything works fine, but the report shown in CC.Net after is not that detailed. I would like to be able to display the uncovered classes, methods and probably the source too.
This is what I have done on the NAnt build script

```
<ncover
  program="${NCoverDir}\NCover.Console.exe"
  testRunnerExe="nunit-console.exe"
  testRunnerArgs="..\..\Vault\AppServices\VaultApp.sln /config:Release /noshadow"
  coverageFile="coverage.xml"
  appendTrendTo="coverage.trend" />
<ncoverreporting
  program="${NCoverDir}\NCover.Reporting.exe"
  projectName="TEST"
  sortBy="Name"
  maxTopUncoveredToReport="20"
  hide="HideFullyCovered"
  coverageTrendPath="coverage.trend"
  outputPath="Ncovercoverage.xml" >
  <coverageDataPaths>
    <include name="coverage.xml" />
  </coverageDataPaths>
  <reports>
    <report format="Xml" reportType="SymbolModule" />
  </reports>
</ncoverreporting>
```

I suspect the report format is limited to Symbol module. How can I get a full coverage report as we get in HTML .

Answer (score 0):

Since CC.NET uses an XML report, not an HTML report, you'd have to generate the HTML like you do now in your build script and then provide a link to it from your webdashboard. The cc.net plugin from NCover only works for single-page report xmls. You can't drill into source code, and etc. Making an HTML report and linking to it from your dashboard is the way to go.